# функция градации цветов (количество n, цвет в формате HEX),при задании начального и конечного цвета

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

нужна функция, или наводки для реализации ее.
На входе:
начальный цвет(HEX), конечный цвет(HEX), количество разбиений.
На выходе:
массив цветов HEX[начальный цвет[n1], цвет[n2], цвет[n3], ..., конечный цвет[n]].
Нужна градация между начальным и конечным цветом, есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Есть идея, начать писать алгоритм сначала на бумажке, а потом код. Что именно вызывает у вас затруднения?

Comment: @Kromster вопрос в том, есть ли уже готовые решения, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: 1) Перевести начальный и конечный HEX в 2 числа 2) Пройтись по интервалу между числами

Comment: @tym32167 такая интерполяция не дает хороших видимых результатов , если уж и говорить о ручной интерполяции, то либо необходимо считать компоненты rgb по отдельности, либо воспользоваться переводом в hsl и интерполировать там, я попозже продемонстрирую результаты

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я совсем не спец в этом, а вам и так поверю, хотя от демонстрации не откажусь :)

Comment: @tym32167 изменил ответ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вполне наглядно, плюсик от меня )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю Вам воспользоваться библиотекой **d3** в частности модулем [d3-interpolate](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate), который много чего умеет  интерполировать, в том числе и цвета, причем не обязательно в `hex`, подойдет любой валидный `css` синтаксис цвета, в том числе и именованные цвета:

```js
let colorsCount = 10;

// создаем интерполятор, он принимает значения от `0` до `1`
let interpolateColor = d3.interpolateRgb('#bad', 'wheat'); 

// получаем  цвета
let colors = Array(colorsCount)
  .fill(0)
  .map((d,n) => interpolateColor(n/(colorsCount - 1)));

d3.select('body')
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(colors)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .style('background-color', color => color)
  .html(color => color)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
```

PS: модуль `d3-selection` для работы алгоритма не нужен, он в сниппете для dom-манипуляций

---

UPD: по просьбам трудящихся соорудил собственную функцию интерполяции rgb(простая линейная интерполяция 3х компонентов по отдельности) и привожу неправильный пример интерполяции значения цвета целиком, как числа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let lerp = (time, left, right) => left + (right - left)*time;

let lerpRgb = (a, b) => time => [
    lerp(time, a[0], b[0]),
    lerp(time, a[1], b[1]),
    lerp(time, a[2], b[2]),
];


let interpolate = lerpRgb([255,0,0], [0,0,255]);
let ctx = draw.getContext("2d");
for(var i=0;i<draw.width;i++){

  let c = interpolate(i/draw.width);
  ctx.strokeStyle = `rgb(${c[0]},${c[1]},${c[2]})`;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(i, 40);
  ctx.stroke();
  c = Math.floor(lerp(i/draw.width, 0xff0000, 0x0000ff));
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + c.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(i, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(i, 90);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="draw" width="500"></canvas>
```